# Why do we need the ```plutus-chain-index``` to run and why does it take so long to sync

Tags: plutus, wallet, cardano-node, pab

I'm trying to set up a PAB in order to test my contracts

Currently I have:

- fully synced a `cardano-node` running on testnet
- fully synced `cardano-wallet` tracking one wallet
- a `plutus-chain-index` syncing at an absurd slow rate
- a `pab` instance that displays

  ```
  [pab:Info:1] [2022-04-11 14:07:59.27 UTC] Restoring PAB state ...
  [pab:Info:1] [2022-04-11 14:07:59.27 UTC] No contract instance were restored in the 
  PAB state.
  [pab:Info:1] [2022-04-11 14:07:59.27 UTC] Starting PAB backend server on port 9080
  ```

and connecting to that instance, for example trying

```
http:localhost:9080/swagger/swagger-ui
```

does not works the first hours but it does after at least 5 hours, even if the chain-index syncing sits at 0.76% after all that time.

my questions are

1. Why do we even need a `plutus-chain-index` instance running if it is ok at 0.76%
2. How can I get more information on when the PAB is ready?

Comment: Where is the progress of chain index now? I have trouble to sync too. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/429

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The chain index provides data such as datums and utxo values.
   Its data from the chain but organized in a way that's more convenient and faster to query than is possible with the node directly.
   It's intended to be a 'db-sync-lite'.
2. You can run with `--verbose` flag. But it will dump a lot of stuff out.
   You should also be able to hit `localhost:9083/swagger/swagger-ui` (provided you are using the default config).

They've been numerous problems with the chain index, with many being fixed recently. I recommended taking the latest version if you aren't already.